# Flutter overlap multiple widgets with dynamic height using Stack or any other approach

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-listview

Flutter is a fairly new framework as of today and there are many setbacks when it comes to flexible design. What I want to achieve can be demonstrated easier by images.

As you see when the tiles have a border-radius such as in the images they have to overlap in order not to leave empty space like in the first image. I achieved this using the 'Stack' widget of course by giving fixed height for the widget above and fixed top padding for the following widget in a loop so that I got the view in the 2nd and 3rd images. However, this approach prevents me from using dynamic sizes within each widget because I cannot get the height of the previous widget in the build-time.

Has anyone faced this kind of UI pattern or a similar one that can help me with this case? I appreciate any collaboration on this.

[image: simple widgets]

[image: overlapping widgets]

[image: overlapping widgets with upper radius]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to calculate things on your own, not taking into consideration how it was painted but precisly how you want it to be painted with math.

Of course to find dynamic values there is this to use inside your `build` function:

```
var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
var width = screenSize.width;
var height = screenSize.height;
```

and based on this you can make your calculations.

If you need to have those values before `build` functions runs, for your `initState` or whataver reasons you can initialize this widget with `width` and `height` if you know what I mean, since `width` and `height` of the screen is equal in everywidget.